# Multiple Robots in Webots and Control Them independently with ROS2?

Tags: ros2, webots, multi-robot

I am following the tutorial of [Setting up a robot simulation in Webots (Basic)](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Setting-Up-Simulation-Webots-Basic.html) which is in *ROS2 humble documentation*. Here I have a .wbt world file, .urdf file according to the tutorial. I have added another robot in the world file and change controller node for each robot specified in the launch file. In the tutorial they have mentioned "if you had more robots in the simulation, you would have to run one instance of this node per robot". This is the part of my launch file where I created the nodes:

```
my_robot_driver_1 = WebotsController(
    robot_name='my_robot_1',
    parameters=[
        {'robot_description': robot_description_path},
    ]
)
my_robot_driver_2 = WebotsController(
    robot_name='my_robot_2',
    parameters=[
        {'robot_description': robot_description_path},
    ]
)
```

After successfully running the code webots starts with 2 robots and the topic list is:

```
/cmd_vel
/my_robot_1/ds0
/my_robot_1/ds1
/my_robot_2/ds0
/my_robot_2/ds1
/parameter_events
/remove_urdf_robot
/rosout
```

Here there is 1 `/cmd_vel` but i need different `/cmd_vel` for each robot like (expected topic list):

```
/my_robot_1/cmd_vel
/my_robot_1/ds0
/my_robot_1/ds1
/my_robot_2/cmd_vel
/my_robot_2/ds0
/my_robot_2/ds1
/parameter_events
/remove_urdf_robot
/rosout
```

In the world file, "controller" field of each robot is exactly the same as in the tutorial `controller "<extern>"`.

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: What's the actual error here? It's not clear what behavior you're observing vs. what behavior you're expecting.

Comment: There is no error. The problem is i have 2 robots but one /cmd_vel. So, if I give Twist message linear x=1 then both the robots move to x direction with value 1. But i need two /cmd_vel topic for those two robots so that I can move them independently. Like if i publish Twist message linear x=1 to /robot1/cmd_vel topic then only the 1st robot moves in x direction and 2nd robot remain in its place.

Comment: I have edited my current topic list and expected topic list in the question. Hope it may help you to understand well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can either use a [namespace](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-ROS2-Launch-For-Large-Projects.html#namespaces) or [remappings](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Node-arguments.html#passing-remapping-arguments-to-specific-nodes) or a combination of both. In your case, it would look something like:

```py
my_robot_driver_1 = WebotsController(
    robot_name='my_robot_1',
    parameters=[
        {'robot_description': robot_description_path},
    ],
    remappings=[
            ('/cmd_vel', '/my_robot_1/cmd_vel'),
    ]
)
my_robot_driver_2 = WebotsController(
    robot_name='my_robot_2',
    parameters=[
        {'robot_description': robot_description_path},
    ],
    remappings=[
            ('/cmd_vel', '/my_robot_2/cmd_vel'),
    ]
)
```

Here is an example of a launch file spawning multiple robots in Webots:
https://github.com/memristor/mep3/blob/b03b6aa0e0de5e5bfe5ec8694cf6f3d21cf697ce/mep3_simulation/launch/simulation_launch.py#L35-L73

Comment: I have tried your method. But the problem remain same. There is just one `/cmd_vel` topic and the name is `/cmd_vel`. No change happened in the topic list.